Why can't you connect to some computers?
In this video: 


Around the 14:00 minute mark, the player tries to "Connect" to the hotel lobby computer, which seemingly fails. (The method call returns "-1".)
I was under the impression you could Connect to any object… Never saw a connect fail like that before.
Are certain computers/objects blocked from Connecting to?

In the follow-up video, the player, Alex, explains that he simply had a typo in the computer name: 

 (Explanation is around the 7:00 minute mark.)
You can Connect to anything! <3
